# Number of strictly increasing sequence not equal a given number.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ denote a natural number. What's the cardinality of the set 
$S_j:=\{ 1 \leq i_1 < ... < i_k \leq n \, | \, i_s \neq j, \, \forall s = 1,...,k\}$, for $j \in \{ 1,...,n\}$?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Is it $\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{2}$?

Comment: try small numbers and see if it is correct?

Comment: It's not correct. You are right.

Comment: btw, index of $s$, should it be up to $k$?

Comment: Sorry, you were right. Fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just have to avoid choosing $j$ and choose a subset of size $k$ from the remaining $n-1$ elements.

$$\binom{n-1}k.$$

Comment: I am stupid :(. Thanks! Just a bit overwhelmed from the continuous reading.

Comment: welcome. just overwhelmed, not stupid. btw, always try to include your attempt when you ask a question, why do you think what you propose could be correct or whatever you have tried and obtained so far. you get to learn more that way.